# Relay for controlling a water pump motor

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, relay

I want to switch on and off a motor with arduino, used for pumping water. I need to have a idea which relay could be used with arduino.

Here is a photo of a similar motor:
[image: Motor]

Comment: In this case an image does not tell a thousand words. In order to get a proper answer, we need to know the specifics of this pump. Voltage? Amperage? AC / DC? How does it work? Perhaps a datasheet?

Comment: You need a relay that can handle the amount of current the motor uses. So check the Amps ratings of the motor and of the relay.

Comment: @Gerben it must handle Starting current. I think some small opto-isolated relay module and big contactor would be the best.

Comment: A relay must also be spec'ed for the voltage it will be switching, to prevent arcing and burning its contacts when they make and break.

Comment: Fairly cheap and quite reliable relays which operate at 5V (5mA to switch closed/open) can be had at a decent price. Mine have an upper limit of 10A, either 250VAC or 30VDC.